# Remove public repository from my GitHub account

Tags: github

In my GitHub account I am seeing two public repository along with my private repository. I am not sure how these public repository came up in my account. Now I want to delete them from my account but as I am not seeing the **Settings** options on the repository page.

Following is the landing page of my account.
[image]

When I search for all types of repository, at that time it is not showing those two public repositories. 
[image]

Comment: You've obscured the names so we've no way to tell. Are those repositories in your account? i.e. where the part of the name before the `/` is your username?

Comment: Yes, before the / is the username. But it is not mine and also these are not my repositories. Here is the link of one of the repository. https://github.com/AseemWangoo/services_demo

Comment: Obviously you can't delete other people's repositories!

Comment: Yes I cannot but how can I remove it from my dashboard so it shows only my repositories when I login.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/about-your-personal-dashboard doesn't suggest it is possible to control which repositories Github adds to the list of "top repositories you use".

Answer (score -1):

can you click into the repositories and hit settings on the far right? scroll down and in the "danger zone" you should be able to delete it, if it is yours, among other options.

[image]

Comment: As I said, I am not seeing the Settings button when I click on the repository.